# Problema con librería fpdf.php

Tags: fpdf, librería

Tengo una aplicación que genera facturas en pdf. Estoy usando la librería fpdf. El problema viene cuando la fila es demasiado extensa y la librería en lugar de cortar el texto al final de la página y seguir en la siguiente, me pasa toda la fila a la siguiente página, dejando la anterior página prácticamente en blanco. También estoy usando la extensión pdf_mc_table.php. Me es imposible poner el código. Siempre me pone que tengo errores. Si fuerais tan amables de decirme como poner un bloque de código php os lo agradecería. Gracias. Un saludo

Comment: Para incluir bloques de código puede usar la [sintaxis de markdown](https://es.stackoverflow.com/markdown#syntax-highlighting). Escribe el bloque de código entre los caracteres: 
``` 
tú código 
```

Comment: Ya lo intento, para me dice que hay errores